# Regex Numerical Range 1 - 1 million

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a expression range for monetary purposes. It needs to be 1 - 1 million and allow commas and periods. I don't need a min/max of (, and .) for correct formatting but I would like the digits after a period to be a min/max of 2 for actual cent values. Thanks

In Range:
640 or 5,000.35 or    999,000

Not in Range:
01 or    1,000,000.01 or  333,567.678

Comment: `I would like the digits after a period to be a min/max of 2 for actual cent values.` - you mean like `5,000.35`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^(1(\.\d{2})?|[1-9]\d{0,2}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d{2})?)|1((,000){0,2}|(000){0,2})(\.00)?$
```

But it would probably easier if you normalize the value first (e. g. remove any character except digits and the `.`) and then parse it.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't... http://regexr.com?30l25 (I'm still working on it myself and it seems like a pain this one...)

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is :

- Use something like that to verify that the input has a specific format :

  (here's a demo - http://regexr.com?30l28)

  `(1[\.,])?([0-9]{1,3}[\.,])?([0-9]{1,3})([\.,][0-9]{1,2})`
- And then test the value range :

  is `value<1.000.000`?

---

My regex is by no means 100% complete, but it DOES verify your general number format though.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious, and combine the regexp with checking of the actual value

Comment: @Presto44 You're welcome, my friend! If you find an answer particular useful, it would be adviseable to mark it as an Answer (the tick next to the answer) so that the community can benefit from it.